# Adding annotations to individual bars on a grouped bar chart (R plotly)

Tags: r, plotly

I have created a grouped bar chart using r plotly showing LGBT population across the various countries in the UK grouped by year. Now I'm trying to add labels to the first and last bar to show the start year and end year of the data, rather than having a legend, but I'm struggling to get the labels to align to the correct bars. I have used the annotations function and manually aligned the two labels by using xshift, but this solution isn't ideal for an html report with zooming etc. I would like to find a better solution that automatically aligns the labels to the grouped bars. Is there a simple way to make the labels align by the year variable so they align with the correct bars?

My data for this chart:

```
# A tibble: 30 × 3
    Year Country          Percentage
   <dbl> <chr>                 <dbl>
 1  2017 Northern Ireland      0.016
 2  2017 England               0.028
 3  2017 Scotland              0.023
 4  2017 Wales                 0.025
 5  2017 UK                    0.027
 6  2018 Northern Ireland      0.016
 7  2018 England               0.029
 8  2018 Scotland              0.026
 9  2018 Wales                 0.031
10  2018 UK                    0.029
11  2019 Northern Ireland      0.017
12  2019 England               0.034
13  2019 Scotland              0.031
14  2019 Wales                 0.039
15  2019 UK                    0.034
16  2020 Northern Ireland      0.018
17  2020 England               0.037
18  2020 Scotland              0.036
19  2020 Wales                 0.042
20  2020 UK                    0.038
21  2021 Northern Ireland      0.023
22  2021 England               0.036
23  2021 Scotland              0.038
24  2021 Wales                 0.047
25  2021 UK                    0.036
26  2022 Northern Ireland      0.023
27  2022 England               0.039
28  2022 Scotland              0.04 
29  2022 Wales                 0.053
30  2022 UK                    0.039
```

Here is my current code chunk.

```
Figure5$Country = factor(Figure5$Country, levels = c("Northern Ireland","England","Scotland","Wales", "UK"))

#wrapping labels on chart
Figure5$wrappedy <- sapply(Figure5$Country,
FUN = function(Country) {paste(strwrap(Country, width = 10), collapse = " <br> ")})

# named color vector
cols <- setNames(c("#12436D","#28A197","#801650","#F46A25","#3D3D3D","#A285D1"), c("2017","2018","2019","2020","2021","2022"))

annoa <- list(x = "Northern Ireland", y = 0.3, text = "2018", xref = "2018", yref = "y", xshift='-354', textangle= -90, showarrow = FALSE, font = list(color = "White", family = 'mono',size = 16, fontface=2))
annob <- list(x = "Northern Ireland", y = 0.3, text = "2022", xref = "2022", yref = "y", xshift='-256', textangle= -90, showarrow = FALSE, font = list(color = "White", family = 'mono',size = 16, fontface=2))

hoverfonts <- list(
  color = "white")
hoverlabels <- list(
  bordercolor = "transparent",
  font = hoverfonts)

#filtering out 2017
plot_ly(Figure5[Figure5$Year !="2017",], x = ~wrappedy, y = ~Percentage,
        type = 'bar', color = ~Year, name = ~Year, colors = cols,
          # marker = list(pattern = list(shape = rep(c("x", "/", ".","",""), each = 5)),
        #               line = list(width = 1.5)),
            hoverlabel = hoverlabels) %>%
                                      # layout to align bar and box traces
  layout(yaxis = list(rangemode='tozero', ticksuffix = "%", title = ""),
         xaxis = list(title = "",categoryarray = ~wrappedy, categoryorder = c("Northern Ireland","England","Scotland","Wales", "UK")))%>%
  layout(margin=list(pad=5)) %>% 
  hide_colorbar()%>%
  layout(annotations = annoa)%>%
  layout(annotations = annob)%>%
  config(displayModeBar = FALSE)%>%
  layout(showlegend=FALSE)

#Create the CSV and Excel Files
downloadButtons(data = Figure5[,c('Year','Country','Percentage')],
           title = "Figure 5: LGBT+ Across the UK Regions (16+)")
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the future, it would be a lot easier to help if when you provided data you pasted the output of `dput(data)` instead.

You didn't provide an example of what you would ideally want, but I *think* you're looking for a multicategory bar chart, where both the years and countries are shown. There are a few different ways you could do this. For example, the years could be text labels on the bars. Another method is to provide two fields for one axis.

The data and objects I used from your question.

```
Figure5 <- structure(list(
  Year = c("2017", "2017", "2017", "2017", "2017", 
           "2018", "2018", "2018", "2018", "2018", "2019", "2019", "2019", 
           "2019", "2019", "2020", "2020", "2020", "2020", "2020", "2021", 
           "2021", "2021", "2021", "2021", "2022", "2022", "2022", "2022", 
           "2022"), 
  Country = structure(c(1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 
                        1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L), 
                      levels = c("Northern Ireland", "England", "Scotland", "Wales", "UK"), 
                      class = c("ordered", "factor")), 
  Percentage = c(0.016, 0.028, 0.023, 0.025, 0.027, 0.016, 
                 0.029, 0.026, 0.031, 0.029, 0.017, 0.034, 0.031, 0.039, 0.034, 
                 0.018, 0.037, 0.036, 0.042, 0.038, 0.023, 0.036, 0.038, 0.047, 
                 0.036, 0.023, 0.039, 0.04, 0.053, 0.039), 
  wrappedy = c("Northern<br>Ireland", 
               "England", "Scotland", "Wales", "UK", "Northern<br>Ireland", 
               "England", "Scotland", "Wales", "UK", "Northern<br>Ireland", 
               "England", "Scotland", "Wales", "UK", "Northern<br>Ireland", 
               "England", "Scotland", "Wales", "UK", "Northern<br>Ireland", 
               "England", "Scotland", "Wales", "UK", "Northern<br>Ireland", 
               "England", "Scotland", "Wales", "UK")), 
  row.names = c(NA, -30L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))

# named color vector
cols <- setNames(c("#12436D","#28A197","#801650","#F46A25","#3D3D3D","#A285D1"), 
                 c("2017","2018","2019","2020","2021","2022"))

hoverlabels <- list(bordercolor = "transparent", 
                    font = list(color = "white"))
```

#### Adding Text to Bars

Adding text to the bars: you'll see that I've added `text` and `textposition` to `plot_ly` and consolidated the parameters you set in your question.

```
plot_ly(Figure5[Figure5$Year !="2017",], x = ~wrappedy, y = ~Percentage,
        type = 'bar', color = ~Year, name = ~Year, text = ~Year, textposition = "outside",
        colors = cols, hoverlabel = hoverlabels, showlegend = F) %>% 
  layout(yaxis = list(title = "", ticksuffix = "%"), 
         xaxis = list(title = "", categoryarray = ~wrappedy,
                      categoryorder = c("Northern Ireland","England","Scotland","Wales", "UK")),
         margin = list(pad = 5)) %>% config(displayModeBar = F)
```

[image]

#### Adding a Multicategory Axis

Here you'll see that that I've flipped the axes that's more for space and clarity. For `y`, I've added 2 columns from your data frame to make a multi-category axis. Since the bars are on the `y`, I've added `orientation = "h"` for horizontal.

When you flip the axes, it reverses the order, so I have `autorange = "reversed"` to return the correct order to the y-axis in `layout(yaxis...`. The rest of the code is based on the formatting provided in your question.

```
plot_ly(Figure5[Figure5$Year !="2017",], y = c(~wrappedy, ~Year), x = ~Percentage,
        type = 'bar', color = ~Year, name = ~Year,
        colors = cols, orientation = "h",
        hoverlabel = hoverlabels, showlegend = F) %>% 
  layout(yaxis = list(autorange = "reversed"), 
         xaxis = list(ticksuffix = "%", title = ""),
         margin = list(pad = 5)) %>% config(displayModeBar = F)
```

[image]

If anything is unclear or if you've got more questions, let me know.

Comment: This is brilliant, thank you. I was hoping to just have labels for the first and last year, how would you recommend i do that?

Comment: If you want it to be text (the first option I provided) the easiest method would be to add another column to the data frame, in that column, have the data corresponding with the first and last year (2018 & 2022), for the other rows, have `""`, then for `text` when you call `plot_ly`, call that column.  (e.g. `mutate(Figure5, txt = ifelse(Year %in% c(2018, 2022), Year, ""))` & `text = ~txt`)

Comment: That's perfect, thanks so much for your help.